# Zookeeper: FAILED TO WRITE PID

Tags: apache-zookeeper

So I'm trying to to get started with Accumulo.  I installed Hadoop and it runs w/o problems but when I try to start Zookeeper I get:

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
-n Starting zookeeper ... 
/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh: line 103: /tmp/zookeeper/zookeeper_server.pid: No such file or directory
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

I've looked around can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: try starting server with "start-foreground" to see full log of problem

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem. In my case was useful to start Zookeeper and directly specify a configuration file:

> /bin/zkServer.sh start **conf/zoo.conf**

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of zookeeper, but it could be a permissions issue trying to write the file `zookeeper_server.pid` or perhaps the directory `/tmp/zookeeper/` doesn't exist and the shell script isn't accounting for that possibility.  Check the permissions and existence of those directories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It was stupid me.  I was supposed to `ssh localhost` first and then run the command.

Answer (score 1):

zookeeper distributed with default conf, uses `/tmp/zookeeper` as `dataDir` for just example sake. It is suggested changing this value in `/path/to/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg` to `/var/lib/zookeeper`.

Creating `/var/lib/zookeeper` needs root access, so `sudo` is required. This directory when created will have following permissions.

```
ls -al  /var/lib/zookeeper/
drwxr-xrwx  4 root           wheel  128 May  9 14:03 .
```

When zookeeper is started without root permission, it cannot write to this directory. hence fails with error

```
... /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh: line 169: /var/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

You need to give write permissions to allow user starting zookeeper to write to `/var/lib/zookeeper`. In my case, as I am using it in local, I used the following command and it worked

```
sudo chmod o+w /var/lib/zookeeper
```