# FAILED TO WRITE PID installing Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to Zookeeper and it has being a real issue to install it and run. I am not sure what is wrong in here but I will explain what I've being doing to make it more clear:

1.- I've followed the installation guide provided by Apache. This means download the Zookeeper distribution (stable release) extracted the file and moved into the home directory.

2.- As I am using Ubuntu 12.04 I've modified the .bashrc file including this:

```
export ZOOKEEPER_INSTALL=/home/myusername/zookeeper-3.4.5
export PATH=$PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_INSTALL/bin
```

3.- Create a config file on conf/zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

and also tried with:

```
dataDir=/var/log/zookeeper
```

and

```
dataDir=/var/bin/zookeeper
```

4.- When running the start command

```
zkServer.sh start or `bin/zkServer.sh start` nothing happens and always returns this

JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/sasuke/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/zookeeper': Permission denied
Starting zookeeper ... /home/sasuke/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh: line 113: /var/zookeeper/zookeeper_server.pid: No such file or directory
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

I have Java installed and inside the zookeper directory there is a zookeeper.jar file that I think it's not running.
Checking here on stackoverflow there was a guy that said he could run zookeeper after typing

```
ssh localhost
```

But when I try to do it I get this error

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Please help. I've being here trying to solve it for too long.

Getting started guide of zookeeper:
http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html
Previous case solved with the shh localhost
[Zookeeper: FAILED TO WRITE PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092636/zookeeper-failed-to-write-pid)

UPDATE:
The permissions for log are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root     4096 Oct 10 07:52 log
```

and for zookeeper:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 zookeeper         zookeeper    4096 Mar 23  2012 zookeeper
```

Should I change any of these?

Comment: Post permissions of `/var/log/zookeeper` ? It seems you do not have the required permissions

Comment: Please,see my answer on the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092636/zookeeper-failed-to-write-pid

Comment: try starting server with "start-foreground" to see full log of problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you do not have the required permissions. The `/var/log` owner is is going to be root. Zookeeper stores the process id and snapshot of data in that directory. The process id of the spawned zookeeper server is stored in a file -`zookeeper_server.pid` (as of 3.3.6)

If you have root previleges, you could start zookeeper with `sudo` (root) previleges, it should work but definitely not recommended. Make sure you start zookeeper with the same(or higher) permissions as the owner of the directory.

Create a new directory in your home folder like `/home/username/zookeeper-data`.
Let `dataDir` point to that directory and it should work.

Comment: I have changed the dataDir as you said and it worked. But would I have any problems later when developing? I have changed the permissions of the log and zookeeper directory allowing the user and group to write on it but it didn't worked. By the way thanks for the asnwer.

Comment: You could also give write permissions on dataDir (`/var/log/zookeeper/` in your case) to the user running zookeeper... `sudo chmod go+w /var/log/zookeeper`

Answer (score 14):

I have had the same problem. In my case was useful to start Zookeeper and directly specify a configuration file:

> /bin/zkServer.sh start **conf/zoo.conf**

Comment: This answer should be higher. Especially if getting the error running as root.

Answer (score 4):

The default zookeeper installation (tar extract) comes with the conf file named `conf/zoo_sample.cfg` while the same extract's `bin/zkServer.sh` expects the conf file to be called `zoo.cfg` thereby resulting in a "No such file or dir" and the "failed to write pid" error. So before running zkServer.sh to start or stop zookeeper instance, either:

- rename the `zoo_sample.cfg` in the conf dir to `zoo.cfg`, or
- give the name (and path) to the conf file (as [suggested by Ilya Lapitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295978/failed-to-write-pid-installing-zookeeper#29347014)), or, of course
- edit zkServer.sh ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Directory for dataDir make sure to use the `-p` option. This will allow subsequent directories to be created as required by the application placing files.

`mkdir -p /var/log/zookeeperData`
Then set:

`dataDir=/var/log/zookeeperData`

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's all kinds of reasons this can happen. So many helpful answers here!

For me, I had improper line endings in my zoo.cfg file, and possibly invisible characters, so zookeeper was trying to create directories like `/var/zookeeper?` and `/var/zookeeper\r`.  Reworking my zoo.cfg a bit fixed it for me, along with deleting zoo_sample.conf.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me due to low disk space. cause zookeeper cant create pid file inside zookeeper data folder.

Comment: How much storage required ?
I'm facing same issue non of the solution working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while starting the zookeeper with this command:

> hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8$ bin/zkServer.sh
> start
>
> ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:
> The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper.

It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in `zookeeper.znode.parent`. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

But running the script as `su` rectified the issue:

> hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8$ sudo bin/zkServer.sh
> start
>
> ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default Using config:
> /home/hadoop/hadoop/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
> Starting zookeeper ... STARTED

Answer (score 0):

Go to /usr/local/etc/
You will find zookeeper directory
delete the directory
and restart the server - zkServer start

Comment: take a look how to make a list [sample list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Change the path give dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper.  If it works then its clearly access issues

But its generally not advisable to use tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an **ownership** issue; running the following solved this for me.

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /var/lib/zookeeper
```

N.B.
I've outlined my steps below which show the error I was getting (the same as the error in this SO question) and the attempt at trying the solution proposed by a user above, which advised to provide `zoo.cfg` as an argument.

```
13:01:29 ✔ ~  :: $ZK/bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.14/libexec/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... /usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.14/libexec/bin/zkServer.sh: line 149: /var/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied
FAILED TO WRITE PID

13:01:32 ✘ ~  :: $ZK/bin/zkServer.sh start $ZK/conf/zoo.cfg
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.14/libexec/conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... /usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.14/libexec/bin/zkServer.sh: line 149: /var/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

```
13:04:45 ✔ /var/lib  :: ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     wheel 128 Apr 19 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root     wheel 864 Apr 19 18:55 ..
drwxr--r--  3 root     wheel  96 Mar 24 15:07 zookeeper
13:04:48 ✔ /var/lib  :: echo $USER
tallamjr
13:06:03 ✔ /var/lib  :: sudo chown -R $USER zookeeper
Password:
13:06:44 ✔ /var/lib  :: ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     wheel 128 Apr 19 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root     wheel 864 Apr 19 18:55 ..
drwxr--r--  3 tallamjr wheel  96 Mar 24 15:07 zookeeper
```

```
13:06:48 ✔ ~  :: $ZK/bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.14/libexec/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

REF:
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked:
I granted the read, write and execute permissions for everyone using the command $**sudo chmod 777 foldername** for the directory zookeeper by going inside the directory /var (/var/zookeeper).

After executing this command try running the zookeeper. It ran in my case

Answer (score -1):

try to use sudo -E bin/zkServer.sh start