# zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied FAILED TO WRITE PID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Sorry, if there are the same question. I'll do project on hbase that need to install zookeeper. So I follow the instruction on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoYteLiNHNc

Finally I want to start zkServer.sh but

```
ardias@Arif-Satellite-C800D:~$ zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh: line 149: /usr/local/hadoop/zoo_data/zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

I think the problem is I am not superuser so I use sudo but

```
ardias@Arif-Satellite-C800D:~$ sudo zkServer.sh start
[sudo] password for ardias: 
sudo: zkServer.sh: command not found
```

I've been search any solutions on
[FAILED TO WRITE PID installing Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295978/failed-to-write-pid-installing-zookeeper) and also
[Zookeeper: FAILED TO WRITE PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092636/zookeeper-failed-to-write-pid)
but it doesn't work on me. There's file myid in /usr/local/hadoop/zoo_data contains character "1".
Anybody have solutions?
This is my zoo.cfg and my ubuntu version is 14.04.

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/usr/local/hadoop/zoo_data
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:
1. change `dataDir` to a directory that `ardias` have permission.
2. find the absolute path of `zkServer.sh` and use `sudo /$absolutePath/zkServer.sh start`

Comment: I used the 2nd option, it works for me on my MAC.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still facing this issue on MAC, then find below

```
ZOO_DATADIR="$(echo -e "${ZOO_DATADIR}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
```

in zkServer.sh file and remove option `-e`  from echo command.

The final command should be `ZOO_DATADIR="$(echo "${ZOO_DATADIR}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"`

Restart zookeeper after this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `zoo_sample.cfg`

```
[hadoop@localhost conf]$ vi zoo_sample.cfg
[hadoop@localhost conf]$ ls
configuration.xsl  log4j.properties  zoo_sample.cfg
[hadoop@localhost conf]$ mv zoo_sample.cfg zoo.cfg
change the zoo_sample.cfg to zoo.cfg
```